# Como reestruturar o index de um array - php

Tags: php, array

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou precisando da ajuda de vcs. É o seguinte: Tenho um array que foi criado a partir de um arquivo CSV de contatos de cliente. Nesse arquivo o que mais me interessa são os números de celulares e em alguns não consta o número.  Blz. Então fiz uma varredura no array em questão e retirei os que estavam com o campo de celular vazios. Só que com isso o Index ficou desordenado, por exemplo:

```
0=> array
     0 => string ...
     1 => string ...
10 => array
     0 => string ...
     1 => string ...
15 => array
     0 => string ...
     1 => string ...
```

E gostaria de ficassem na ordem correta tipo 1, 2, 3... Não sei se me fiz entender direito, mas seria reordenar o index do array para que ele ficasse sequencial novamente.

Obrigado

Comment: a resposta te ajudou? Se sim, procure marcá-la para ajudar outros colegas.

Answer (score 1):

Dani, é o seguinte. Existe uma função nativa do PHP que faz exatamente o que você precisa.

Chama-se `array_values();` ela retorna todos os valores do `array input` num `array` indexado numericamente.

um exemplo hipotético:

```
$arr[0] = '10';
$arr[2] = '20';
$arr[5] = '45';

$arrN = array_values($arr);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arrN);
```

Retorno:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "10"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "20"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "45"
}
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Obrigado Leandro, não pude testar ainda, mas daqui a pouco vou ter tempo e testo. Assim que tiver news, posto aqui.

Thx

Comment: ótimo, muito bom. Dê um feedback para os demais colegas que tiverem a mesma dúvida serem ajudados tbm